# image uploading using MultiPart

Tags: java, spring, file-upload

I am writting the code to upload a file using Spring's MultipartFile on server for that I have written following code

```
if(!partnersContentBean.getFile().isEmpty()){
        MultipartFile file = partnersContentBean.getFile();

    if(file.getOriginalFilename().endsWith(".jpeg")||file.getOriginalFilename().endsWith(".jpg")|| file.getOriginalFilename().endsWith(".gif")){
        File dirPath = new File("//125.22.60.37/image/dev/cmt/");
       if (!dirPath.exists()) {
               dirPath.mkdirs();
       } 
        URL url = new URL("http://125.22.60.37/image/dev/cmt/"); 
           File destination = new File(url.toString());
           file.transferTo(destination);
           String url1 = request.getContextPath() + ApplicationConstants.imageUploadDirectory + file.getOriginalFilename();
           System.out.println(url.getPath());
           partnersContentBean.setPartnerImagename(file.getOriginalFilename());
           partnersContentBean.setPartnerImagepath(destination.getPath());


        }else
        {
            userModuleDetailBean.put("errorMessage", "File should be in type of jpg,Jpeg or GIF");
            return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("partnersAdd_CMT.htm"),"userModuleDetailBean",userModuleDetailBean);
        }
     }
```

but when I upload a file I get following exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: `http:\125.22.60.37\image\dev\cmt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`  dont know what path should i give to upload it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to transfer the uploaded file to another remote server (`125.22.60.37`). You can't do that - you can't represent an HTTP URL using a `File` object.

FileUpload is for storing the uploaded files to your local machine. Once there, you can worry about moving them to another remote server, but the two tasks are separate.

Comment: i mean is there any way to do this shal I move manually transfer those file using anothe client like ssh etc. or any other way

Comment: @Vipul: That depends on your setup. I suggest you close this question, and open another one which is not related to file upload.